# Use multiple bl_space_types to place the same toolbar on multiple locations

Tags: python, add-on

So I'm not sure if this will be possible at all, but someone might have an idea for a workaround for this problem.

So if I have made a toolbar, e.g. (short version)

```
class add_item(Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
```

But I would like to have this toolbar placed in multiple toolbars so it'd become something like this (code below doesn't actually work, just an example of what I'd like):

```
class add_item(Panel):
    bl_space_type = ['VIEW_3D', 'IMAGE_EDITOR', 'NODE_EDITOR']
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
```

Would something similar to this be possible to do without duplicating all the code for the toolbar multiple times, just to then change the `bl_space_type`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using a loop to generate dynamically named panels, each with the desired `bl_space_type` ([based on this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352781/how-to-set-class-names-dynamically)):

```
import bpy

def panelFactory( spaceType ):
    class NewClass( bpy.types.Panel ):
        bl_space_type = spaceType
        bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
        bl_label       = "add_item_%s" % spaceType

        def draw( self, context ):
            layout = self.layout
            layout.operator( "mesh.primitive_cube_add" )

    NewClass.__name__ = "add_item_%s" % spaceType
    return NewClass

spaceTypes = ['VIEW_3D', 'IMAGE_EDITOR', 'NODE_EDITOR']

for spaceType in spaceTypes:
    panelFactory( spaceType )

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

This code will add the "Add Mesh Cube" operator in a new panel to the "Misc" tab in each of the desired windows (space types).

Answer (score 3):

You can use inheritance to share code between panels while customising parts that are unique to each editor.

```
class MyBasePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """A Panel to show in many places"""
    bl_label = "My Tools Panel"
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'

    def mydraw(self, context):
        # do nothing here so each class can add it's own thing'
        pass

    def draw(self, context):
        self.mydraw(context)
        row = self.layout.row()
        row.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

class My3DViewPanel(MyBasePanel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'

class MyNodesPanel(MyBasePanel):
    bl_label = "My Nodes Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'

class MyImagePanel(MyBasePanel):
    bl_space_type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'

    def mydraw(self, context):
        row = self.layout.row()
        row.label('For the Image editor')
```