# How to display custom panel in two spaces?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

My custom panel work good in the **VIEW_3D** space.

```
bl_label = "My Panel"
bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
bl_region_type = "UI"
bl_category = 'MY'
```

I want to display panel in two spaces: **VIEW_3D** and **IMAGE_EDITOR**.

I try write so:

```
bl_label = "My Panel"
bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D", "IMAGE_EDITOR"
bl_region_type = "UI"
bl_category = 'MY'
```

but it doesn't work. How to make it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Subclasses and inheritance

Code based on [this answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44052/use-multiple-bl-space-types-to-place-the-same-toolbar-on-multiple-locations) and updated for 2.8x according to [API changes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons):

```
class MY_PT_CustomPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """A Panel to show in many places"""
    bl_label = "My Tools Panel"
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def mydraw(self, context):
        # do nothing here so each class can add it's own thing'
        pass

    def draw(self, context):
        self.mydraw(context)
        row = self.layout.row()
        row.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

class MY_PT_Viewport(MY_PT_CustomPanel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'

class MY_PT_ImageEditor(MY_PT_CustomPanel):
    bl_space_type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'

    def mydraw(self, context):
        row = self.layout.row()
        row.label(text="For the Image editor")
```